# How to sign document from web using Token USB (Digital Signature)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I found that most of those who have done this signing process doing it through JS using hwcrypto JS library but I didn't find any demo and I need to know if there is another way exists or not, and thanks to all who will answer.

Comment: Is there a specific type of token or just a hardware key?

Comment: Please show any work you have completed thus far. The more effort you put into this the more likely your question will get answered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JerodG I didn't write its code yet I am still investigating the case but I found this tutorial and I think this library is not supported anymore.                   
  https://gk.palem.in/digital-signature.html